# How to create Solr request with shard.preference=replica.leader?

Tags: solr

I have solr request with shards.preference param.
Example of request:

```
https://host:port/solr/my_collection/select?debugQuery=on&q=acc:100012&shards.preference=replica.leader:false
```

Example of solr error:

```
"error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Invalid shards.preference type: replica.leader",
    "code":400}
```

How i need to change the request to get the result?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe replica.leader is an option for shards.preference. It's only replica.type and replica.location see: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/distributed-requests.html

Answer (score 0):

In the solr9 it's a valid parameter ,you could refer to this doc:https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/9_1/deployment-guide/solrcloud-distributed-requests.html#shards-preference-parameter